# Need package libxml-2.0, can only find libxml2?

Tags: package-management, compiling, source-packages

EDIT 2:
The root cause of this problem was that I ignored the fact that this line:

sudo apt -y build-dep gnucash

which is recommended in the build instructions failed.

After investigating what the message

E: You must put some 'deb-src' URIs in your sources.list

meant, and how to fix it, the cmake operation completed successfully and the build itself is now underway.

I guess the days of ./configure are gone...

EDIT 1:
Evidently I didn't pay close attention after I installed the dev packages (prior to posting this). The failure changed from wanting libxml to libxslt... I'm working on that and subsequent issues, but this question is "solved". Apologies for failing to wear the right glasses and failing to pay close enough attention :(

---

I'm trying to build gnucash, it requires libxml-2.0 >=2.9.4

However, my system has libxml2, version 2.9.10 (including the dev parts), and this is not resolving that dependency.

Is there a different package libxml-2.0? If so where (it doesn't install if I just try to get it :)

Is there some other route to resolving this dependency?

Comment: You're compiling from source?  It is possible there are issues with the `Makefile`, `CMakelists.txt`, or whatever it uses that is making it unable to find `libxml2` properly?  Can you update your question with the relevant output during compiling?

Comment: If you're *building* stuff that has libxml2 as a prerequisite, then you likely need the `libxml2-dev` development package. This provides a `libxml-2.0.pc` pkg-config file (which is what the build tool is likely complaining about)

Comment: @steeldriver I noted that I have the dev parts, but will add more diagnostic output.

Comment: @Ray Adding more output...

Comment: @Ray apologies, I evidently wasn't wearing the right glasses see update above, consider this resolved (though the build isn't yet complete!)

Comment: @steeldriver  apologies, I evidently wasn't wearing the right glasses see update above, consider this resolved (though the build isn't yet complete!)

Comment: No apologies needed!  Good to hear you were able to solve your problem!

Comment: Providing your OS/release is always helpful on anything related to package issues, as packages are built for specific releases.  Without your release did you expect us to guess from the *depends* rules mentioned?